Почему постеры разных размеров?
Всем доброго времени суток, вывожу постеры через JSON, но при выводе постеры становятся разных размеров... не могу найти причину. Буду благодарен в решении проблемы.


"use strict";
let url = "https://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=c286dd4c&s=";

const 
  body = document.querySelector("body"),
  moviePoster = document.querySelectorAll(".item"),
  block1 = document.querySelector("div.block-D-none"),
  blockClose = document.querySelector("div.window"),
  windowClose = document.querySelector(".closeWindow"),
  divMovieContainer = document.querySelector("div.container-postr"),
  templatePostr = document.querySelector(".movie-content").content,
  search = document.getElementById("search"),
  btnSearch = document.querySelector(".btn-search"),
  spinner = document.querySelector('#spinner');
//header - nav
const btnFilm = document.querySelector('a.film').href = url,
      btnSerial = document.querySelector('a.serial'),
      btnMultFilm = document.querySelector('a.multfilm');

spinner.addEventListener('click', getInfoMovies);

getInfoMovies(); 


async function getInfoMovies() {
  try {
    const textSearch = search.value;
    const response = await fetch(`https://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=c286dd4c&s=${textSearch}`);
    const { Search } = await response.json();
    createNameMovie(Search);
  } catch (error) {
    showErr(error);
  }
}

function showErr(err) {
  body.innerHTML = `<span class="error">ERROR:${err}</span>`;
}

function createNameMovie(Search) {
  for (let movie of Search) {
    const fragment = templatePostr.cloneNode(true);
    fragment.querySelector(".name-movie").textContent = movie.Title;
    fragment.querySelector(".date-movie").textContent = "Date: " + movie.Year;
    fragment.querySelector(".poster-img").src = `${movie.Poster}`;

    divMovieContainer.append(fragment);
  }
};


function clearInfo() {
  divMovieContainer.textContent = "";
}



//buttons




search.addEventListener("keydown", (event) => {
  if (event.code == "Enter") {
    clearInfo();
    getInfoMovies();
  }
});

btnSearch.addEventListener("click", () => {
  clearInfo();
  getInfoMovies();
});


//ModalWindow



// divMovieContainer.addEventListener("mouseover", (event) => {
//   if (event.target !== divMovieContainer) {
//       const item = event.target.closest(".item");
//       const modal = item.querySelector(".window");
//       modal.classList.add("block");
//       modal.classList.remove("block-D-none");
   
//   }
// }),

//   divMovieContainer.addEventListener("mouseout", (event) => {
//     if (event.target !== divMovieContainer) {
//         const item = event.target.closest(".item");
//         const modal = item.querySelector(".window");
//         modal.classList.remove("block");
//         modal.classList.add("block-D-none");

//     }
//   });
* {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
}

.wrap {
    background-image    : url(movie-background-collage.jpg);
    /* background-repeat: no-repeat; */
    min-width           : 320px;
    position            : relative;
    padding-top         : 200px;
    background-size     : cover;
}

.wrap-center {
    max-width: 1100px;
    margin   : 0 auto;
}

header {
    display       : flex;
    flex-direction: row;

    align-items     : center;
    background-color: white;
}

header>ul {
    display        : none;
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size      : larger;
    font-weight    : 800;
    padding        : 0 .2em .3em .6em;

}


#spinner {
  
    height: 60px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: contain;
    /* background-color: #ededed; */
    background-image: url(data:image/gif;base64,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);
  }

header>ul>li>a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color          : gray;

}

header>ul>li>a:hover {
    padding-bottom: .6em;
    box-shadow    : inset 0 -2px blue;
    transition    : .3s ease;
}

header>ul>li {
    padding: 0 .5em 0 .4em;
}

.logo {
    display        : flex;
    align-items    : center;
    font-size      : x-large;
    text-decoration: none;
    letter-spacing : .2em;
    color          : black;
}

.icon-logo {
    padding-right: .5em;
}

.group-logo {
    margin     : .3em 0;
    margin-left: .6em;
}

.btn-search {
    position: absolute;
    margin  : .5em;
}

.group-search {
    flex-grow   : 1;
    display     : none;
    margin      : .3em 0;
    margin-right: .6em;
}

.group-poisk {
    display        : flex;
    align-items    : center;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    flex-grow      : 1;
}

.story {
    height       : 31px;
    width        : 100%;
    box-shadow   : 1px 0px 6px blue;
    border-radius: 11px;
    padding-left : .7em;
    font-size    : large;

}

.login {
    margin-left     : 1em;
    border-radius   : 7px;
    border          : none;
    background-color: darkblue;
    font-size       : large;
    color           : white;
}

.login:hover {
    background-color: blue;
}

.form {
    display        : flex;
    justify-content: center;

}

.search-btn {
    top                : 28px;
    right              : 310px;
    position           : absolute;
    /* background-color: white; */
}


.desc-text {
    background-color: rgb(208, 206, 206);
    padding         : .2em 0 1em .6em;

}

.name-site {
    letter-spacing: 0.2em;
}




.text-color {
    color        : white;
    margin-bottom: .8em;
}

img {
    max-width       : 100%;
    /* border-radius: 10%; */

}


main {
    background-color: #ededed;
}

.container-postr {
    padding        : 1em;
    display        : flex;
    flex-direction : row;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap      : wrap;

}

.item {

    width : 42%;
    margin: .5em .7em;
}


.url-movie {
    display   : block;
    position  : relative;
}

.desc {
    position  : absolute;
    left      : 0;
    right     : 0;
    bottom    : 0;
    z-index   : 10;
    padding   : .4em;
    color     : #fff;
    text-align: center;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) -33%, rgb(11, 7, 55) 73%);
}

.name-movie {

    width      : 100%;
    font-size  : calc(14px + 2 * ((100vw - 420px) / 860));
    font-weight: 600;
    margin     : 0;
}

.rating {
    display        : flex;
    flex-direction : row;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin-top     : 0.3em;
}


.date-movie {
    margin          : .5em;
    position        : absolute;
    z-index         : 99;
    padding         : 3px 5px;
    border-radius   : 3px;
    background-color: rgba(39, 39, 137, 0.868);
    color           : #fff;
    font-weight     : 600;
    font-size       : 13px;
}

.error {
    color: black;
}

footer {

    display        : flex;
    flex-direction : column;
    justify-content: space-between;

    align-items     : center;
    background-color: rgb(9, 9, 54);
    color           : white;
    padding         : 1em 0em;
}

.group-logo-foot {
    margin-left   : .6em;
    display       : flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items   : center;
}

.foot-menu {
    display       : flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items   : center;
    margin        : 0 1em;
    font-size     : larger;
}

.foot-menu>ul {
    padding        : 0;
    margin-top     : 0;
    list-style-type: '›';

}

.foot-menu>ul>li>a {
    text-decoration: none;
    padding        : 0 .6em;
    color          : white;

}



ul>li {
    padding-bottom: .5em;
}

ul>li>a:hover {
    color: blue;
}

/* window modal*/
span {
    user-select: none;
}

button {
    user-select: none;
}



.block-D-none {
    display: none;
}

.block {
    position        : absolute;
    inset           : auto;
    transform       : translate(-35%, -75%);
    width           : 40vw;
    height          : 60vh;
    background-color: black;
    opacity         : 1;
    border-radius   : 5%;
    z-index         : 999;

}

.block2 {
    width          : 100%;
    height         : 100%;
    display        : flex;
    flex-direction : column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items    : center;
}

.closeWindow {
    width      : 5vw;
    height     : 5vh;
    font-weight: 900;
    color      : black;
}


@media(min-width:500px) {
    .item {
        width: 33.33%;
    }

    footer {
        flex-direction: row;
    }

    .group-logo-foot {
        align-items: flex-start;
    }

}

@media(min-width:700px) {
    .item {
        width: 27%;
    }

    footer {
        flex-direction: row;
    }

    .group-logo-foot {
        align-items: flex-start;
    }

}

@media(min-width:900px) {

    .group-search,
    header>ul {
        display: flex;
    }


    .item {
        width: 16.66%;
    }

}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="wink.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrap">
    <div class="wrap-center">
    <header>
<div class="group-logo"><a class="logo" href="#"><img class="icon-logo" src="ico-logo.png" alt="">NAZFILM</a></div>
<ul>
    <li><a class="film" target="_blank">Фильмы</a></li>
    <li><a class="serial" target="_blank" >Сериалы</a></li>
    <li><a class="multfilm" target="_blank">Мультфильмы</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="group-search">
    <div class="group-poisk">
        <input id="search" class="story form__email"  type="text" value="Harry-Potter">
        <span class="btn-search form__btn"><img src="ico-poisk.png" alt=""></span>
    </div>
         <button class="login openModalWindow">Войти</button>
</div>
    </header>
<main>
    <div class="container-postr">
    
</div>
<div id="spinner"></div>
    <img id="spinner" src="" alt="">
</main>
<div class="desc-text">
        <h3><span class="name-site">NAZFILM</span> – фильмы в HD онлайн бесплатно и без регистрации!</h3>
        <span>Современный портал nazfilm вас точно порадует: на сайте собраны тысячи фильмов,
        которые можно просматривать онлайн в высоком качестве. Удобный,
        простой и комфортный «кинотеатр на дому» предлагает смотреть новинки совершенно бесплатно,
        то есть значительно экономит ваше время и деньги на поиск кинозала и покупку билетов.
        Фильмы, представленные на сайте, рассортированы по категориям и жанрам: Лордфильм регулярно добавляет не только популярные киноленты,
        но и сериалы, и мультфильмы в приятной озвучке и хорошем качестве.
        Смотреть кино можно круглосуточно и в любой точке мира – мы публикуем новинки,
        которые помогут отдохнуть после тяжелых будней и еще раз встретиться с любимыми героями.
        Официальный сайт Лорд Фильм дает возможность смотреть любимые фильмы и сериалы с любого устройства.
        Это может быть компьютер, планшет, а также смартфон на IOS или Android.
        Умный проигрыватель определит оптимальный режим просмотра для вашего девайса,
        а вам останется только подобрать увлекательные фильмы онлайн из огромного архива и наслаждаться просмотром!</span>
    </div>


<footer>
    <div class="group-logo-foot"><a class="logo text-color" href="#"><img class="icon-logo" src="ico-logo.png" alt="">NAZFILM</a>
    <span>
       <span class="name-site">NAZFILM</span> - сайт Назфильм онлайн в хорошем качестве бесплатно.
       <br>
<a class="text-color" href="https://mail.ru/po" target="_blank">boss.fataliev@mail.ru</a> - почта для обратной связи.
    </span>
    </div>
    <div class="foot-menu">
        <p>Главное меню</p>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">Фильмы</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Сериалы</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</footer>
</div>
</div>
<template class="movie-content">
    <div class="item">
        <div class="date-movie"></div>
        <a class="url-movie" href="https://mo.lordfilm15.com/filmy/51352-chuzhoj-romul-2024.html" target="_blank"> 
            <div class="movie-poster-img">
            <img class="poster-img">
        </div>
        <div class="desc">
            <h3 class="name-movie"></h3>
            <div class="rating">
                <div class="rat-kp">КП</div>
                <div class="rat-imdb">IMDB</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
            
            <!--open window-->
            <div class="block-D-none window">
                <div class="block2">
                </div>
              </div>
            </a>
    </div>
</template>    
    <script src="wink.js"></script>
</body>
</html>




У вас ширина блоков одинаковые, а пропорции картинок нет, поэтому и получаете блоки разной высоты

Подскажи пожалуйста, как можно решить проблему эту ? если она вообще решается...

Несколько вариантов: сплюшить / обрезать картинки чтобы они стали одинаковых размеров; дорисовать картинки до одинаковых размеров; смириться и добавить задний фон чтобы не слишком отличались

ээхх, ладно, тогда оставим так, что уж... Спасибо большое за советы
